# loosing model instance after saving in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, tastypie

I'm using [backbone](http://backbonejs.org) with [tastypie](http://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie) adapter and jquery for interacting with DOM. I found something in backbone that I can't understand. I tried to simplify the code for this question.

Here is my app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Point = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            lat:0,
            lng:0
        },
        urlRoot: '/api/v1/point' ,
        initialize: function(attributes){
            var that = this;
            $('#b1').bind('click',function() {
                that.set('lat',that.get('lat')+1);
            });
            $('#b2').bind('click',function() {
                that.save();
            });
            $('#b3').bind('click',function() {
                console.log(that.get('lat'));
            });
        }
    });

    point = new  Point ();

    //****

    $('#b1').click();
    $('#b2').click();
    $('#b3').click(); // >> 1

    $('#b1').click();
    $('#b2').click();
    $('#b3').click(); // >> 2

    //****
});
```

And my html:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/backbone-tastypie.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>

<button id="b1">b1</button>
<button id="b2">b2</button>
<button id="b3">b3</button>
```

As you see, I'm calling clicking on buttons in the code and the console is logging '1' and then '2' as expected.

The problem occurs when I am removing code between stars (//***) and pressing these buttons 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3' manually in browser and got '1' and '1' in console.

I wait for response from server for 1 second and check for it in console but the behavior of app is still the same: '1', '2' with a code with stars and '1', '1', with the button pressing.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wait for response from server for 1 second and check for it in console but [...]

Changing the model manually (click the button using your mouse) instead of programmatically (`click()`) is the crucial part here.

I assume **you do not return the final model from your server**, as Backbone update's your model with that data.

See [section 53](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-53) and

```
if (options.wait) {
  if (attrs && !this._validate(attrs, options)) return false;
  current = _.clone(this.attributes);
}
```

[section 55](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-55)

```
options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
  done = true;
  var serverAttrs = model.parse(resp);
  if (options.wait) serverAttrs = _.extend(attrs || {}, serverAttrs);
  if (!model.set(serverAttrs, options)) return false;
  if (success) success(model, resp, options);
};
```

of the [Backbone.js documentation](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html). Especially these lines:

`var serverAttrs = model.parse(resp);` (Parse model data from response)

`if (!model.set(serverAttrs, options)) return false;` (Update your model's attributes)

When your first code (the one where you `click()` the buttons) runs, it increases your  models attribute and loggs it before the server returns. Thats

**Note:** using the `wait` option or a `setTimeout()` in your 2nd press of button three in your first code would equal the behaviour.

But what you want, is to return a *valid* model from your server (after persisting it).

**Off topic tip:** you should not bind your model and your view in the models `initialize`r or `constructor` as it would couple them too tight and they wouldn't be interchangable. (For this question, it is certainly acceptable. ;)